# Optimal plan for PostgreSQL with ORDER BY for two column from same index

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, query-optimization, postgresql-9.5

I have a table with columns: id, user_id, parent_id, date_m, media_type, name

Also we have indexes:

- (user_id, parent_id, date_m, media_type, name) - **index1**
- (user_id, parent_id, name) - **index2**

Now the query, that we had at first:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE user_id = 2
    AND parent_id = 1
    AND date_m > '2018-09-01T11:41:24'::timestamp
ORDER BY date_m
LIMIT 100
```

This query used **index1** and everything was fast.
But we found that this `ORDER BY` clause doesn't create unique order -> it can skip some rows when there're rows with same date_m.

Tried to use `ORDER BY date_m, id` - scheduler started using **index2** and became slow because now we filter each row with clause `date_m > '2018-09-01T11:41:24'::timestamp`

Then we tried to use such query

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE user_id = 2
    AND parent_id = 1
    AND date_m > '2018-09-01T11:41:24'::timestamp
ORDER BY date_m, name
LIMIT 100
```

It was OK for this task but not the best decision in general, cause for other cases `name` could be also the same. Nevertheless scheduler again used bad **index2** and this time it was strange because in **index1** it should be stored in the same order as we define in `ORDER BY` clause, also all columns from `WHERE` statement are in this index. You can see it with the very first query

Update:
here is DDL

```
create table if not exists table_name
(
    user_id               bigint                                              not null,
    parent_id             uuid                                                not null,
    id                    bytea                                               not null,
    name                  text                                                not null,
    date_m                timestamp with time zone default now()              not null,
    date_removed          timestamp with time zone,
    media_type            media_type,
    
    constraint uk_table_name_user_id_parent_id
        unique (user_id, parent_id, name)
);

create index if not exists ix_table_name_user_id_parent_id_date_m_media_type_name
    on table_name (user_id, parent_id, date_m, media_type, name);

create type media_type as enum ('image', 'video');
```

For statement with `ORDER BY date_m` plan is

```
Limit  (cost=15.79..30.17 rows=1 width=1680) (actual time=2.450..2.450 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.41..15.79 rows=1 width=1680) (actual time=2.449..2.450 rows=1 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan using ix_table_name_user_id_parent_id_date_m_media_type_name on files f  (cost=0.83..2.85 rows=1 width=737) (actual time=0.867..0.868 rows=1 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((user_id = <some_uuid>) AND (parent_id = <some_uuid>::uuid) AND (date_m >= <some_date>::timestamp without time zone))
 Planning time: 0.310 ms
 Execution time: 2.516 ms
```

And for statement `ORDER BY date_m, name` plan is:

```
Limit  (cost=15.78..26.14 rows=1 width=1680) (actual time=2458.236..2458.236 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Result  (cost=5.42..15.78 rows=1 width=1680) (actual time=2458.235..2458.236 rows=1 loops=1)
         ->  Sort  (cost=5.42..5.43 rows=1 width=1672) (actual time=2457.913..2457.913 rows=1 loops=1)
               Sort Key: date_m, name
               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.28..5.41 rows=1 width=1672) (actual time=2408.711..2457.906 rows=1 loops=1)
                     ->  Index Scan using uk_table_name_user_id_parent_id on files f  (cost=0.70..2.73 rows=1 width=737) (actual time=2408.666..2457.861 rows=1 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: ((user_id = <some_uuid>) AND (parent_id = <some_uuid>::uuid))
                           Filter: (date_m >= <some_date>::timestamp without time zone)
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 23179
 Planning time: 0.298 ms
 Execution time: 2458.311 ms
```

Comment: Could you please share the results from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for both SQL statements? And share the DDL for all tables and indexes involved? All in plain text, as an update to your question. And what PostgreSQL version do you use?

Comment: "_it was strange because in index1 it should be stored in the same order as we define in ORDER BY clause_" This is not correct. Index 1 has `media_type` in between the two columns in the `ORDER BY` (namely `date_m` and `name`). Therefore the entries in the index are _not_ ordered in the manner which you request. You'd need a different index to do what you're asking (and you should try to use a unique value if possible as you were alluding to)

Comment: @FrankHeikens updated, hid sensitive data, but it should be easy to understand

Comment: @user20042973 Is there a way to make unique order for first query that uses **index1**?

Comment: With just two options for media_type, I wouldn't add this column to the index ix_table_name_user_id_parent_id_date_m_media_type_name. That should now cover your query, all the WHERE conditions and the sort order.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I reduced set of values for media_type in order to hide any information about real DDL. In reality it has 20-30 values.

But as I see now, it's hardly possible to use **index1** because if media_type. Do you know how to create unique order and avoid pagination bug with only `ORDER BY date_m`?

Comment: I would create index3 as `(user_id, parent_id, date_m, id)`.

Comment: 9.5 is EOL. Use something newer.

Comment: @jjanes we're in the process of migrating, but:
1) It's not fast and important task to be done
2) It is not gonna solve my problem

Comment: There are 6, almost 7, new releases after version 9.5. And each one of them improved the query planner.

Comment: It would indeed be curious if incremental sort doesn't solve the problem.  What newer version did you test with?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify your requirement. It's obvious you want no more than 100 rows. And it seems your table contains enough duplicate data that you won't get all rows with particular duplications of table values when you limit the result set to 100. Clarity about your duplicate-handling requirement is a good first step to designing an appropriate index for your query.